# what is the default activation function of dense layer in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, layer, activation

i read the documintation for keras, and i found that when we ignore the activation function it will be just a simple linear function

```
activation: Activation function to use. If you don't specify anything, no activation is applied (ie. "linear" activation: a(x) = x).
```

but also by default the `bias` is `True`, and I try this example, and it solved my problem and gave me the correct weight:

[image]

So what actually the default activation function here, and how can I detect it?

Thanks

Comment: It is a linear layer, also why do you think it can not solved by a linear dense?

Comment: i know it is linear, but it is just f(x) = x
or 
f(x) = sum(x * w + b)>>>> because it is look like this>>>

Comment: Documentation says `a(x) = x`, not `f(x) = x`. Because `f(x) = x` is the identity function, your problem here can be modeled as `f(x) = 2x + 10`, it is linear relationship so no non-linear activation is needed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify an activation function, the value of a neuron will just be a weighted sum of inputs and biases. Applying an activation function happens **after** the sum is calculated so if you don't specify any, it will simply remain like that.

Comment: it means something like this:
sum(input * w + b)

Comment: Basically, yes. If you don't use any activation it will be like that. If you use, let's say, sigmoid, then it will be sigmoid(sum(input*w + b)). The documentation part a(x) = x simply means the result before and after activation is the same (so basically there is no activation function applied).

Comment: but this 
sum(x * w + b)
also will change the weight ? why it is not consider as activation?